# django empty query not checking at None

Tags: django, python-2.7

I Wrote the following code to get whether any value is present in the database or not

```
def databaseCheckIP(self,ip):
    # 1 means IP is Available and 0 means IP is Not Available
    details = Details.objects.get(ipAddress = ip)
    if details is not None:
        return "1"
    else:
        return "0"
```

It is returning "1" when i have the corresponding data

else it throws 500 internal Error when there is no corresponding data,
please tell how to check when there is no corresponding data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QuerySet.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) doesn't return `None` if no record is found. As the documentation says, it raises `DoesNotExist`. [Catch the exception.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) method:

```
details = Details.objects.first(ipAddress=ip)
```

Or more suitable [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
if Details.objects.exists(ipAddress=ip):
    ...
```

Comment: if Details.objects.exists(ipAddress = ip):
        return "1"
    else:
        return "0" 

I tried the same it didn't Worked

Comment: It should work. The purpose of this method is exactly the checking the presence of the data in the queryset.  Are you sure that you wrote `exists()` and not the `exist()`?